# How to run part of code when screen is off. even when my activity is closed

Tags: android

I am new to android app development...

I am trying to create a app which runs a part of code when SCREEN is OFF and runs some other part of code When SCREEN is ON...these things should happen when i check the checkbox in my activity...

presently i am using the below code in my "ACTIVITY.java" file but its not working..

Any advice?? Please help...

---

### code

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
CheckBox checkBox = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    
    checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.my_check_box);
    boolean isChecked = getBooleanFromPreferences("isChecked");
    Log.i("start",""+isChecked);
    checkBox.setChecked(isChecked);
    
    
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            
            Log.i("boolean",""+isChecked);
            MainActivity.this.putBooleanInPreferences(isChecked,"isChecked");
            
             if(isChecked){
                 final PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
                 
                 if( pm.isScreenOn())
                     
                 {
                 
               //some code  
                 }
                 
             else{ 
        //some code
                 } 
             }
            }    
                 
             }
             
        }
     });
    
}



public void putBooleanInPreferences(boolean isChecked,String key){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, isChecked);
    editor.commit();        
}
public boolean getBooleanFromPreferences(String key){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Boolean isChecked = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, false);
    return isChecked;       
}
```

}

Comment: use services for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use android sevices for background task.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html